# Simplify not simplifying expression involving square roots of squares

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a complicated function that is returning a simple expression. The symbols a and b are unassigned. I have not been able to get Mathematica to simplify the expression. (This is only a simple example; I have the same problem with more complicated expressions). Here is what is returned by my function:

```
-Sqrt[(a^2/(a^2 + b^2)^2)] + a/(a^2 + b^2)
```

I try to simplify:

```
Simplify[%, Assumptions -> Element[a || b, Reals]]
```

but I get the same result. What am I doing wrong? Is this an issue with a and b being unassigned? (Does Simplify ignore unassigned symbols?)

I tried FullSimplify with the same result.

Answer (score 3):

`||` is the `Or` logic operator; you want the pattern operator `Alternative`. which is `|`.

Try

```
Simplify[expn, Element[a | b, Reals]]
```

or

```
Simplify[expn, Element[{a, b}, Reals]]
```

Both give

> ```
> (a - Abs[a])/(a^2 + b^2)
> ```

Comment: Or (in v11.3)  `-Sqrt[(a^2/(a^2 + b^2)^2)] + a/(a^2 + b^2) // ComplexExpand // 
 Simplify[#, Element[{a, b}, Reals]] &` evaluates to 

`Piecewise[{{(2*a)/(a^2 + b^2), 
       a < 0}}, 0]`